# JS - Issues making a custom AJAX function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to make a function to handle my AJAX post stuffs.
I was able to get it to send the data, but am having issue receiving data back from the request.

Essentially, I have a function called `ajaxPost(paramArray, target)`, what this does is it accepts the parameters and puts them into a string to submit to the `target`.

I think the issue comes from `ajaxReq.onreadystatechange`, I think it is skipping over that and ending the script.

I do not know if I am properly explaining what I mean, here is the script:

```
function ajaxPost(paramArray, target){
    var param = '';
    var key;
    for (key in paramArray){
        param = param + key + '=' + paramArray[key] + '&';
    }
    param = param.substring(0, param.length - 1);

    var ajaxReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajaxReq.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxReq.readyState == 4 && ajaxReq.status == 200){
            return ajaxReq.responseText;
            document.write('Test?');
        }
    }
    ajaxReq.open('POST', target, true);
    ajaxReq.setRequestHeader('Content-type', "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajaxReq.send(param);
}
```

This is the function that 'does the work', and here is an example of a function that calls the above function:

```
function submitPost(form){
    var title = form.title.value;
    var text = form.textBody.value;
    var name = form.nameOfPoster.value;
    var paramArray = new Array();
    paramArray['title'] = title;
    paramArray['text'] = text;
    paramArray['name'] = name;
    if (ajaxPost(paramArray, 'post.php')){
        location.reload(true);
    }
}
```

This essentially sends the parameters to `ajaxPost()`, and if it returns something it reloads the page.

As I said, I think it is ignoring that one part referenced at the beginning of this post. I am just wondering if I can halt the function until that data is received.

Please do not tell me to use jQuery, I am experimenting with javascript :)

Thanks.
Please do include other tips if you have them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronouse. The way you are trying to use it will not work as `ajaxReq.onreadystatechange` function will be executed after request is done. At the same time, script execution will not stop. So, this:

```
if (ajaxPost(paramArray, 'post.php')){
        location.reload(true);
}
```

will be executed before `ajaxReq.onreadystatechange`

What you should do, is to pass a callback to your function:

```
function ajaxPost(paramArray, target, callback){
    var param = '';
    var key;
    for (key in paramArray){
        param = param + key + '=' + paramArray[key] + '&';
    }
    param = param.substring(0, param.length - 1);

    var ajaxReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajaxReq.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxReq.readyState == 4 && ajaxReq.status == 200){
            callback(ajaxReq.responseText);
            document.write('Test?');
        }
    }
    ajaxReq.open('POST', target, true);
    ajaxReq.setRequestHeader('Content-type', "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajaxReq.send(param);
}
```

and than:

```
function submitPost(form){
    var title = form.title.value;
    var text = form.textBody.value;
    var name = form.nameOfPoster.value;
    var paramArray = new Array();
    paramArray['title'] = title;
    paramArray['text'] = text;
    paramArray['name'] = name;
    ajaxPost(paramArray, 'post.php', function(res) { if(res)  location.reload(true); });
}
```